# R presentation (rpres) goes black in full screen mode

Tags: r, rstudio, rpres

Whenever I take an `.Rpres` file full screen under the latest RStudio (v0.99.902) on macOS every slide after the intro has a black overlay that does not disappear.

While the window is minimized we have:

[[image: Windowed Rpres]]

Under full screen mode (press `f`), switching from the title slide to the subsequent slides yields:

[image: Full Screen Bug]

Code used:

```
Lecture 4: The Art of Life
====
author: 385
date: Today
autosize: true

On the Agenda
====

- Learn about functions
- Learn about other things..

> Only this text appears
```

Comment: hmm. Yes, I can replicate that problem in FF on Windows. You can probably work around it by either displaying it in the IDE or in browser but not full screen or using HTML tags. But still, it's weird.

Comment: this happens to me using chrome but not safari or firefox on a mac. f11 doesn't do anything as suggested below.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too.

F11 didn't help me either, until after I started viewing the slides full-screen using the menu bar:
[image]

This made my slides full-screen (with the nice white background), then I could use F11 to toggle off the full-screen option. Does this work for other folks?

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly adding font and background colors in `custom.css` worked for me.

```
.reveal .state-background {
  background: white;
} 
.reveal {
  color: black;
}
```

(You also obviously have to add `css: custom.css` under the title slide's title.)