# image and text side by side Rstudio presentation / .rpres

Tags: html, css, r, rpres

I'm trying to achieve the basic layout that 99% of presentations use where a slide has a title some text below that and then an image below that with text to its side. Apparently, this is a very difficult task to accomplish in rstudio presentations (the [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847371/two-column-layouts-in-rstudio-presentations-slidify-pandoc) was no help). How do I go about doing it? Below is what I'm looking for (made in powerpoint):

[image]

Here's what I've tried thus far:

```
Title
====================================
incremental: false

<font color = "darkred">
 Additional Text Goes Here</font>

<div align="center">
<img src="fake.png">
</div>

***

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>


- Text goes here
- Text goes here
- Text goes here
```

Which clearly produces a ridiculous outcome:

[image]

Problems with the current output:

- Title and text below it are too close
- Text below title too far to left (should align with title)
- Image should also align with title

Here's my attempt at addressing those issues:

```
Title
====================================
incremental: false

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div style="margin-left: 1em;">
<font color = "darkred">
 Additional Text Goes Here</font>
</div>

<p>&nbsp;</p>


<div align="center">
<img src="fake.png">
</div>

***

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>


- Text goes here
- Text goes here
- Text goes here
```

And I tried

```
<div style="padding: 10px;">
<font color = "darkred">
 Additional Text Goes Here</font>
</div>
```

Both of those did nothing, I tried messing around with the css and added the following:

```
<style>
p {
    text-indent: 240px;
}
</style>
```

Which produced the following:

[image]

But some major problems persist:

- This changed the title for all my sides -I cant have that. I tried changing the `p` to the appropriate header lable `h5` (5th page) but that did nothing.
- The image isn't perfectly aligned
- I'd like to reduce the space b/w the title and the text below I know I can remove `<p>&nbsp;</p>` but then the spacing is too close (like in the first image)

My knowledge of html and css is next to nothing so thanks for bearing with me. I simply in disbelief that the most basic feature of slide shows is some how missing from Rstudio's quintessential format of presentations (images with text above and adjacent) -clearly I must be missing something. Any help is much appreciated.

Oh and two final points -when I turn to the actual slide it appears exactly how I want it (if I've gotten rid of the spacing and css styles) for perhaps less than a second or 2 (while its rendering). Also, I thought I'd check Rpubs just to check my sanity -assuming there would be tones of projects with this layout on there. I went through maybe 30 different presentations and either 1) the presentation did not have a layout slide in the form I desire (2/3rds of them) and the remaining presentations that did have a layout all were suffering from the exact same problem I am. Every single presentation with a format like that look absolutely terrible like the images above. I guess the good folks at Rstudio are busier with more important tools than making Rstudio presentation format a reasonable choice of slideshow to use, which is absolutely fine. Unfortunately, slidify is a nightmare in developmental purgatory, beamer's templates are very arcane looking, and I cant find a single example of an ioslide project on the internet so I didn't even bother going down that rabbit hole. I'm open to suggestions of other presentations formats that can be used with R otherwise I'm stuck taking screenshots of my R output and code to to upload to a powerpoint (****cringe****). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have found a "solution". In the examples I posted above I was examining the plots in Rstudio's Viewer as well as in my Safari browser. Both produced identical results but I decided to give it a go with Chrome and Firefox and they both produced the same nice looking format. I guess Rstudio presentation's formats are browser dependent -perhaps not surprising as I've seen different browsers recommended for different sites/uses but I did not see anything in regards to that documented on Rstudio's help forum.

[image]

**UPDATE:** I just double checked the documentation for Rstudio and it looks like they say chrome, firefox, ie, *and safari* are [supported](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200714023-Displaying-and-Distributing-Presentations).

[image]

**UPDATE 2:** I just spotted another discrepancy between the browser outputs. When I go into full screen mode (using the key `F`) in Firefox everything is fine as expected and in Safari everything looks as it does in non-full screen. In Chrome fullscreen, however, the background color of the all the slides following the title slide are rendered black. This has been noted [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37902552/r-presentation-rpres-goes-black-in-full-screen-mode) too.

[image]

I'm baffled. I just have to prey that any subsequent obstacles I face aren't specific to firefox since I'm running low on browsers and I'll move to powerpoint before installing IE on my computer.

Answer (score 4):

A little late to the party, but another solution can be found [here.](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486468-Authoring-R-Presentations)

The appropriate formatting would then be:

```
Two-Column Slide
====================================
First column (Will appear on left)
![alt text](myimage.png)
***
Second column (Will appear on right)
```

Comment: This works, as does `----` to announce the second column.