# Full screen image Rstudio presentation

Tags: css, r, markdown, rstudio, rpres

I'm trying to add a fullscreen image to the title page an Rstudio presentation. I followed the advice from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28916359/rstudio-0-98-1028-add-background-image-only-to-title-slide).

```
<style>
.section .reveal h1 {
   color: darkred;
   font-size: 1.5em;
   text-align: center;
}

.section .reveal .state-background {
    background: url(fake.png) ;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

</style>

Text
========================================================
width: 2000
height: 900
author:
date: 
autosize: true
incremental: true

<center> <font color = "darkgreen">Text</font> </center>

<center>
<small> 
<font color = "white", size="5.5">
 Text
</font> 
</small>
</center>
```

In Rstudio's viewer everything looks fine:

[image]

But in firefox, safari, and chrome I get no background

[image]

Any ideas? It appears .rpres is still in heavy development -many [bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39585761/image-and-text-side-by-side-rstudio-presentation-rpres/39586731#39586731), etc.

Comment: Please provide Html code also

Comment: @Santosh the problem isnt related (i dont think) to the body but I threw it in there in case it helps, thanks!

Comment: I'd use [`rmdshower`](https://github.com/mangothecat/rmdshower) vs rpres - http://mangothecat.github.io/rmdshower/skeleton.html

Comment: @hrbmster thanks for the suggestion, taking a look at it now.